# Cannot force unwrap the value

Tags: swift

```
var tuples: String! = "subash"
if let goin = tuples {
    print(goin!)
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> Cannot force unwrap the value of non-optional type String

I don't what happening  constant goin is same as tuples but why it's showing me an error when I do force unwrap

Instead of the above code, this is running well:

```
var tuples: String! = "subash"
print(tuples!)
```

But kindly I need a solution to my above problem

Comment: *“goin is same as tuples”* – no, it isn't. I recommend to read about optional binding in the Swift book.

Comment: i have read the definition (since 3 hrs )but i cannot able to find the difference  can you please sort out? @MartinR

Comment: `tuples` is an optional. `goin` is not.

Comment: Don't you want `tuples` to be `String?`. There is no good reason to create an implicitly unwrapped optional string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's something normal if you know how optionals work.

Inside the if statement, the right expression must be either Optional or Implicitly Unwrapped Optional, BUT NOT "normal" value.

This is the correct code:

```
let tuples: String! = "subash"

if let goin = tuples {
    print(goin) // NO NEED to unwrap, because going IS NOT Optional
}
```

The reason this code runs fine:

```
var tuples: String! = "subash"
print(tuples!)
print(tuples)
```

... is because tuples is of type Implicitly Unwrapped Optional.

However, in general cases like this:

```
let myVar: String! = "some string"

if let myNewVar = myVar {
    // Some code...
}
```

... `myVar` is always an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional, whereas `myNewVar` is of String type, because of how Optional Unwrapping works with `if let` statements.

Finally, if we unwrap the value this way:

```
let myVar: String! = "some string"

if let myVar = myVar {
    // Some code...
    print(myVar)
}
```

The printed value is the `temp myVar`, which is of type `String` and shadows the Implicitly Unwrapped `myVar` variable we initially declare.

Comment: @MartinR Please check the updated code. Should be print(goin) not print(goin!), because going is not Optional, therefore it cannot and it should not be unwrapped.

Comment: because i ruined your code its giving me the same error as before

Comment: but as per the apple docs, it  have to run without error even its     print(goin!)

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry I didn't check in Xcode initially, but now I've figured it out. Code is updated and runs OK,

Comment: @worksubash Please accept my answer, if it's helped you and it's correct.